# check whether a File exists in one Dir based on the file name from another directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am new to PowerShell i am trying to write a script which takes a file name from source and check if the file with same name exists in the target directory by using the `Test-Path`. If the file exists then it should die or the script should succeed.

I am trying some thing like below it is not working. Can you let me know what need to be changed in the below script?

```
$Filename = "$tDir\Source\risk*.txt*"

if (!(Test-Path -path "$Dir\Target\$Filename" -pathtype leaf)) {  
    exit 1
} else {
    exit 0    
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Are you receiving an error which you can post or can you post what you want the intended result to look like?

Comment: The variable `Filename` doesn't look like a filename to me, but a regex.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ...

```
$Local:tDir   =  "C:\temp"
$Local:Dir    =  "....."

Get-ChildItem "$tDir\Source\risk*.txt" | Foreach-Object {
    $Local:Filename = $_.Name
    Write-Host ("- {0,30}" -f $Filename) -NoNewline
    if (!(Test-Path -Path "$Dir\Target\$Filename" -PathType leaf)) {  
        Write-Host  1
    } else {
        Write-Host  0    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
!(Test-Path "$Dir\Target\$Filename")
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation would be more helpful than a single line of code.Don't you think ?